# HTML Email using Foundation by Zurb - trouble centering an element

Tags: html, sass, zurb-foundation

I hope all is well.  I'm presently practicing building an HTML email using the Foundation for Emails framework by Zurb. I can't seem to center a certain span element.  I designed it to look like a button using SCCS.  I figure if this span can't be centered, then an actual button or form / input combo element would present as slightly more difficult to maneuver.

Here's a snippet of the image output.  As you can see, I managed to center the other span elements, but notice the "See Deal" element is slightly out of alignment with the rest of the image.  When I inspect the element, for some reason it's not lined up within the box like the rest of them.

Been working on this for about a day and I can't seem to get it figured out.  Any and all insight is always most welcomed and appreciated.

[image: Output Image]

Here's my HTML portion of the code:

```html
<container class="other-deals-container">

    <row class="other-deals">
      <columns>
        <row class="offer">
          <columns>
            <img src="{{root}}/assets/img/kayak-images/cancun.png">
            <p>Cancun: 4 nights with air and Melody Maker Cancun stay.  Price reflects MIA departure, other cities available.</p>
            <span class="save_amount">Save up to 65%</span>
            <span class="tiny_info">CheapCaribbean.com</span>
            <span class="price">$689+</span>

            <center>
              <span class="button">See Deal</span>
            </center>
        
          </columns>
        </row>
      </columns>
    </row>

</container>
```

Here's the CSS / SCSS portion of the Code:

```html
.other-deals {
    background: #f1f4f7;
    background-color: #f1f4f7;

    .offer {
        background: #ffffff;
        background-color: #ffffff;

        .columns {
            th {
                padding-top: 20px;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
                padding-right: 20px;
                padding-left: 20px;
            }
            & > table {
                table-layout: fixed;
            }
        }
    }

    img {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    p {
        color: black;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    span {
        color: black;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;

        &.save_amount {
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #1d93f5;
        }

        &.tiny_info {
            font-size: 10px;
            font-weight: 300;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }

        &.price {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 600;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }

        &.button {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-left: 40px;
            padding-right: 40px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my issue.  I had to step away (always a good tactic).

To remove the button, I removed the  tags and placed contents into a span element nested into a link  element.  That seemed to have done the trick.  Thanks to everyone that read this post.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: "Readex Pro", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
}
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.button:active {
  transform: translatey(3px);
}
.other-deals-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
}
p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
}
.save-amount {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 17pt;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.tiny_info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 7pt;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.price {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
```

```html
<!-- google fonts-->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Readex+Pro:wght@200;300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- end google font -->

<container class="other-deals-container">

  <row class="other-deals">
    <columns>
      <row class="offer">
        <columns>
          <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
          <p>Cancun: 4 nights with air and Melody Maker Cancun stay. Price reflects MIA departure, other cities available.</p>
          <span class="save-amount">Save up to 65%</span>
          <span class="tiny_info">CheapCaribbean.com</span<br>
            <span class="price">$689+</span>

        </columns>
        <button class="button">See Deal</button>
      </row>
    </columns>
  </row>

</container>
```